# Can the Swift adaptation of KVO handle custom targets?

Tags: swift, key-value-observing

To do KVO in Swift, you make a `NSObject`-based `@objc` class, and can observe properties that are stored and marked `@objc` and `dynamic`.

- Can you observe on computed properties (that are `@objc` and `dynamic`)?

I just glanced at the Objective-C guide, and it showed you could mark KVO dependencies for a computed property.  And (I think) observe on an array property changing at the element level.  Can either of those be done in Swift?

Comment: If a property is a computed property, what exactly would you be observing? What would constitute a change in a computed property? I mean, I know what we're observing with a stored property: it's that the setter is called, thus changing the property's value in a KVC compliant way. What's the analogy for a computed property?

Comment: "Can either of those be done in Swift?" Did you try? And please give an example of what you want to observe.

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> Can you observe on computed properties (that are `@objc` and `dynamic`)?

Yes. Just mark your computed property `@objc` and `dynamic` and when the setter for the computed property is called, then the observer will be called.

---

For example, consider a synchronizer class, where you want to observe the computed property, `value` :

```
class Synchronized: NSObject {
    private var _value: Int
    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "synchronizer", attributes: .concurrent)

    init(value: Int) {
        _value = value
        super.init()
    }

    @objc dynamic var value: Int {
        get { queue.sync { _value } }
        set { queue.async(flags: .barrier) { self._value = newValue} }
    }
}
```

Here, the `value` is a computed variable, which you can `set` and all the usual KVO can take place:

```
token = foo.observe(\.value, options: .new) { _, change in
    print(change.newValue ?? "Unknown")
}
```

This observer is triggered when the `value` setter is called.

---

The only trick is going to be if you want the KVO triggered notification if the the value returned by the computed property changes via something other than the computed property’s setter. In that case, you’d have to manually issue the KVO notifications.